# CakePHP session reading a variable that is not set

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Basic question, I am setting a variable (facebook id) in cakephp session if the user is from facebook, if the facebook id is set in the session I want to do different thing. **How can I check that?**

I am doing something like:

```
if(isset($this->Session->read("fbid")) && $this->Session->read("fbid") != "")
```

**Is this correct?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is giving me an error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: fixed the above error by setting the value of read to a variable before passing it to isset

Comment: You should read http://kunststube.net/isset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Session Component has a method called check.

```
if ($this->Session->check('fbid')) {
    //fbid exists in session
}
```

[CakePHP manual page on the session component's methods](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1466/Methods)

Comment: up to date documentation: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-SessionComponent.html#_check